# Why people cause so much pain even if everyone wants to be happy?

Tags: ethics

Everyone on this world wants to be happy. It's in human nature to be satisfied, pleasured,... **happy**. Happiness usually means painless state of mind when we enjoy beautiful present. In this desire for the happiness we often make a lot of pain to ourselves and people around us, why is that?

I've often caught myself and other people doing full opposition of what I/they wanted to achieve. Why is that?

---

Why do I think about that?

In past two years I've read some books with spiritual, peaceful content and I've got new way to look at world/people. So I'm peaceful man now, even if I do KickBox :). But this peacefulness it's kinda my weakness that many people are using against me. So I'm thinking why do they doing it even if I'm nice to them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most contemporary philosophers would interrogate the concept of happiness, pain, and even "human nature".  By interrogate, I mean that they would suggest that these concepts are not inherent and have tricky meaning that may not be the same across time or even across individuals.  And they would find this interrogation more interesting that your question.

However, the philosophic school of Utilitarianism addresses your specific question at length.  In specific terms, Utilitarianism suggests that ethical decisions should be made by the metric of the amount of happiness could be generated from the options under consideration.  Sounds like your thinking of similar issues.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utilitarianism

Answer (score 0):

- From a survival prospective, it is clearly not necessary to be happy to survive. Thus survival, continued existence, relies not on "happiness" but on the circumstances of survival. Thus "everybody" who fits the case qualifies as *survivor*, but not necessarily as happy survivor.
- Because it is unnecessary, it is at an even further remove that members need not be "consistent" with the "happiness" of peers in their species. Thus, we can argue that there at most a modicum of selection pressure on goodwill toward others.
- In addition, people are "happy" at least instantaneously. The idea of being *continuously* happy might simply be a projection from the observed to an area where it does not apply.
- Furthermore, the continually morose might be a variation, again allowed by the lack of significant selection pressure on a state of general happiness.
- Next, the projection from wants to happiness may simply be illusory. Since we are not happy and we do not have what we currently want, we may project that the instantaneous happiness of getting more things that we want will make us more generally cheerful. It's at least likely that we simply become unsatisfied with what we have and continue the cycle that wanting and not having is a case for not being "happy".

Thus, very little supports the state of "everyone happy".

- Want, we can want a person who will never regard us to "love us"; we can *want* to see and talk to dead loved ones. We can *want* to be the first 4-foot guard in the NBA. "Wants" are merely suppositions which have a promise of a type of release from desire, or at least an augmentation of oneself.
- Say the 4-footer gets his shot in the NBA. Absent amazing talent which warrants his position, his team may *want* another player. They *want* to win. They *want* to score more points--or have fewer points scored against them. Thus it is extremely unlikely that both sets of wants coincide.
- "Happy-ness" may simply be the meta-want of all wants the individual perceives. Some reasonable and some not.

Now, the question isn't "Why aren't we happy" it's "Why do people cause so much pain".

- I think it's a very IS-y statement to say that people cause as much pain as they do. This is the exhibited tendency of people to cause pain. Thus it is the case that people cause a certain amount of pain. That pain may be referred to as "so much" and happiness does not necessarily describe a real state, nor does a want imply a feasible case for its object. It is the nature of want to be relatively free of real cases. So it is the nature of wants to have a range extending to the counter-factual.

  Thus we have satisfied all conditions of pain, happiness and want for happiness: Happiness does not exist or is elusive or hard or non-probable or a mere mistaken projection from the experience of being happy. Wanting it doesn't make it any more real. And the infliction of pain *is* real.

With IS-supremacy, I simply drop the mic. But, with an IS-OUGHT dialog or "super-position" we are still left with "what do *we*, as perceivers of this case, do with this?"

Again given the model of survival, we perceive and analyze, quantify and model *as* a function of survival. But it is a trivial case that all those who perceive this case accomplish, for the present, survival. The concept of "*X* IS *A*" does not exist, *for its own sake*, but for perceivers and the continuation of their expression as perceivers.

And the perceiver *wants* a level of "well-being" that it does not have. Now, at this point we can simply step back outside our heads, that our mode of sensing the "truth" of the previous point. Outside we "observe", wants being counter-factual, does not entail the achievability of the want. But empirical wisdom tells us what is not *tried* is not achieved anyway.

It is at least *as* analytic to recognize that the variation that we are has a very nature to attempt to achieve his projected well-being. It's just that the case of success in this is not inevitable, but the counter is very unlikely absent an attempt to achieve what is not.

Thus while what we regard as "success" is reducible only to a change of state in the objective sense, it leaves a large part of the word, outside of simply brute existence, which allows us to experience even excruciating agony, "made up".

Do we want "success"? But then *why* want something which has little correspondence to any objective case, simply imputed to be a part of the brute existence which allows us to experience pain--and thus substantiate an amount of pain?

Again an IS-"collapse" (in the quantum metaphor of the IS-OUGHT super-position) gives *us* nothing, if we then make the OUGHT a thrall to the IS.

Thus here is my full answer:

1. It IS the case.
2. The full version is very much not likely to be the case, (yet still *intriguing* and desirable)
3. We can achieve non-realized states of "success" toward this.
4. But, to say more is not justified, for the time, by my attempted analytic method.
5. So, it just is the case.